# Have I converted this MATLAB simulated waveform code to Python correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I am working to convert this MATLAB code that generates a waveform to Python. For context this is a simulation of band excitation response from an atomic force microscope (not relevant to code error). The graph that is generated from `r_vec` in MATLAB is different from when I generate it in Python, am I converting the MATLAB code to Python correctly?

I have the attached the graph that is plotted in MATLAB which is how it should look versus what Python generates. Here is the MATLAB code below.

[MATLAB plotted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1lAk.png)

[Python plotted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rISaE.png)

```
%simulate BE response over a line scan

% define experimental parameters
IO_rate = 4E6; %[samples/sec]
N_pixels = 128; % number of pixels along a line scan
N_points_per_pixel = 2^13; % number of data points per pixel
w1 = 200E3; % lower edge of band
w2 = 400E3; % upper edge of band
noise_level = .1; %add noise to the signal

w_vec = -IO_rate/2: IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel : IO_rate/2-IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel; %frequency vector over a pixel

% vary A, wo, Q, and phase over pixels
p_vec = (0:N_pixels-1)/N_pixels;
A_vec = sin(2*pi*3*p_vec)+2; %amplitude
wo_vec = 250E3 + 100E3*p_vec; %resonance
Q_vec = 100 - 50*p_vec; % Q-factor
phi_vec = sign(p_vec-.5); % phase

% build drive signal, define in the Fourier domain
D_vec = zeros(size(w_vec));
D_vec( ((abs(w_vec)<w2) + (abs(w_vec)>w1)) == 2 ) = 1; % drive bins located within upper and lower band edges
band_ind = find( (((w_vec)<w2) + ((w_vec)>w1)) == 2 );

d_vec = fftshift(ifft(ifftshift(D_vec))); % find drive signal in the time domain

% build response at each pixel
R_mat = zeros(N_pixels,N_points_per_pixel);
r_mat = zeros(N_pixels,N_points_per_pixel);
for k1 = 1 : N_pixels
    H_vec = (A_vec(k1).*wo_vec(k1).^2).*exp(1i*phi_vec(k1))./(w_vec.^2 + 1i*wo_vec(k1)*w_vec/Q_vec(k1) - wo_vec(k1).^2); %cantilever transfer function
    R_mat(k1,:) = (H_vec.*D_vec); %response of the cantilever in the Fourier domain
    
    %determine response in the time domain (this is a little hokey, but it should work for simulation)    
    r_mat(k1,:) = fliplr((real((ifft(fftshift(R_mat(k1,:)))))));    
end

% build full response in the time domain;
r_vec = reshape(r_mat.',[ 1 N_pixels*N_points_per_pixel]);

% add noise
r_vec = r_vec + noise_level*2*(rand(size(r_vec))-.5);

figure(6)
clf
plot(r_vec)
```

Here is the converted Python code

```
#simulate BE response over a line scan

# define experimental parameters
IO_rate = 4000000 #[samples/sec]
N_pixels = 128 # number of pixels along a line scan
N_points_per_pixel = 8192 # number of data points per pixel
w1 = 200000 # lower edge of band
w2 = 400000 # upper edge of band
noise_level = .1 #add noise to the signal

w_vec = np.arange(-IO_rate/2, IO_rate/2-IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel + 1, IO_rate/N_points_per_pixel)

p_vec = np.arange(0, N_pixels+1)/N_pixels
A_vec = np.sin(2*np.pi*3*p_vec)+2 #amplitude
wo_vec = 250E3 + 100E3*p_vec #resonance
Q_vec = 100 - 50*p_vec # Q-factor
phi_vec = np.sign(p_vec-.5) # phase

D_vec = np.zeros(np.size(w_vec))
ind = (abs(w_vec)<w2) & (abs(w_vec)>w1)
D_vec[ind] = 1 #assign those indices to 1.
band_ind = np.argwhere(((w_vec)<w2) & ((w_vec)>w1)) #check again

d_vec = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(D_vec)))

R_mat = np.zeros((N_pixels,N_points_per_pixel))
r_mat = np.zeros((N_pixels,N_points_per_pixel))

for k1 in range(N_pixels):
    H_vec = ((A_vec[k1]*wo_vec[k1]**2)*np.exp(1j*phi_vec[k1])/(w_vec**2 + 1j*wo_vec[k1]*w_vec/Q_vec[k1] - wo_vec[k1]**2)) #cantilever transfer function
    R_mat[k1,:] = (H_vec*D_vec) #response of the cantilever in the Fourier domain
    r_mat[k1,:] = np.flip((np.real((np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(R_mat[k1,:])))))) 

#build full response in the time domain;
r_vec = np.reshape(r_mat.T, (N_pixels*N_points_per_pixel))

#add noise
r_vec = r_vec + noise_level*2*(np.random.rand(np.size(r_vec))-.5)

plt.plot(r_vec)
```

Comment: For stating `p_vec` you have a vector between `0` and `127` in MatLab but between `0` and `0` and `129` in Python. Same with the for loop, you loop 1 more time in Python. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @ZWang I just removed that part and updated the code.

Comment: Ryan, you have posted [an identical (?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63201952/2749397)  that I have answered before I saw this one.  I suggest you to close/delete this one.

Comment: Just saw it, thank you so much! @gboffi